# HTML5 slider input - have range?

Tags: html, input, slider

Is there a native HTML5 input for a slider with a range (ie 2 inputs) like this?:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

Comment: Looks like the answer is no: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753946/html5-form-slider-with-two-inputs-possible