# Getting values from html inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input element that is a range slider that I wanted to turn into a slider with a lower and an upper bound. This feature isn't implemented yet for range although it's being discussed. [As you can see this is a popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753946/html5-form-slider-with-two-inputs-possible).

My issue is that the way I was retrieving the results of the slider no longer seems to work and I don't understand why.  My original slider works like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="slider">
            <input id="slider" type="range" value="0" oninput="sliderAmount.value = slider.value" min="0" max="100" step="1" />
            stuff: <output name="sliderAmount" for="slider">0</output>
        </label>
    </form>
    <div id="stuff"></div>
    <script>
        amt = document.getElementById("slider");
        var amtChange = function () {
            document.getElementById('stuff').innerHTML+='<div>'+amt.value+'</div>';
        };
        amt.onchange = amtChange;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Every time you slide the bar it updates the stuff div with the new result. I want to be able do the same thing with the jquery slider but update the stuff div with the range instead.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#slider-range").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 500,
                values: [75, 300],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
                }
            });
            $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
                " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
        <input id="amount" type="text" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        <div id="slider-range"></div>
    </form>
    <div id="stuff"></div>
    <script>
        amt = document.getElementById("amount");
        var amtChange = function () {
            document.getElementById('stuff').innerHTML += '<div>' + amt.value + '</div>';
        };
        amt.onchange = amtChange;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be able to pull the range from the slider input. If I go into the console in Chrome for the jquery example I can type `amt.value` and it will return the value every time. What am I missing here?

Comment: This `$("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);` line is doing so..Make the necessary changes there...

Comment: Once the `amount` is retrieved can you not retrieve it again?

Comment: `onchange` event may not fire with jQuery slider..http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change may help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the `change()` method for `input` while changing it's value.

Try this:

**DEMO: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pqf1dk9e/)**

```
 $(function () {
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [75, 300],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]).change();
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
            " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)).change();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I wasn't familiar with needing to add the `change()` method.

Comment: No problem. You are Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change event of jQuery UI Range Slider. Use it and append updated changes to stuff like below.

```
$(function () {
        var changes = '';
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [75, 300],
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
            },
            change: function (event, ui) {
                changes += '<div>' + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1] + '</div>';
                $("#stuff").html(changes);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
            " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

    });
```