# Mapping an HTML5 range slider min and max to array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, range

I am putting together an HTML5 form for music teachers so they can classify their music library a bit easier. One of the requested elements is a double handled range slider that would be able to define the range of a particular piece.  This is all fine if we were talking 0 to 100, but we're talking G-Flat 3 to B5, a series of arbitrary values that wouldn't normally be found on a range slider.

What I'm thinking of doing is creating an array of all the different note ranges from G-Flat 3 to B5 (lowest to highest), and then somehow mapping those to a double handled range slider.  Problem is, I don't know how to do that, nor do I know if it is even possible.

In essence, I would like to create an array:

```
Array = ['Gb3', 'G3', 'G#3', 'Ab3', 'A3',... 'A#5', 'Bb5', 'B5'];
```

Somehow match those up to numeric values:

```
0 = 'Gb3';
1 = 'G3';
2 = 'G#3';
```

And then map those to a double handle range slider.

Any one know if there is a library, or plugin or magic toadstool that can point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE:** I want to thank EVERYONE who posted to this. There are so many fantastic answers, I'm having a very difficult time choosing "the" answer.

Comment: It seems you've already matched notes up to numeric values: their index. If it's "all fine if we're talking 0 to 100," then it seems 0 to `n` array indices should be no problem.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this polyfill](http://leaverou.github.io/multirange/) for a [now-abandoned](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1520) proposal to add a `multiple` attribute to the `<input type="range">` spec. It's simple and works well enough, but has an unfortunate bug: Event handlers aren't fired for when the second handle is moved. It's pretty easy to work around, though:

```js
const notes = ['Gb3', 'G3', 'G#3', 'Ab3', 'A3', /* ... */ 'A#5', 'Bb5', 'B5'];

function handleChange() {
  const { valueLow, valueHigh } = this;
  const lowNote = notes[parseInt(valueLow, 10)];
  const highNote = notes[parseInt(valueHigh, 10)];
  console.log('%s to %s', lowNote, highNote);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const input = document.querySelector('input[type=range]');
  input.addEventListener('input', handleChange);
  input.nextElementSibling.addEventListener('input', handleChange.bind(input));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LeaVerou/multirange/gh-pages/multirange.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LeaVerou/multirange/gh-pages/multirange.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Change me: <input type="range" min="0" value="0,7" max="7" step="1" multiple>
```

As you can see, I've set the `<input>`'s `min` attribute to 0, `max` to the highest index in `notes` (`notes.length - 1 == 7`), and `value` to `0,7`. In addition to adding an `'input'` event handler to `input`, I've added the same handler to `input.nextElementSibling`. The latter is the generated "ghost" element which renders the second handle. It's necessary to bind the event handler to `input` because the "ghost" input doesn't have `valueLow` and `valueHigh`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a javascript object. Here is an example.

HTML

```
<input type="range" value='0' min='0' max='3'>
<div class='sound'></div>
```

jQuery

```
var obj = {
  0 : 'Gb3',
  1 : 'G3',
  2 : 'G#3'
}

$('body').on('change', 'input[type=range]', function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $('.sound').text(obj[val])
});
```

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING ME..... it's really THAT easy?!?!? I still want to use the slider though. like put those NOTE values into tooltips above the handles, or permanently on the ends.  I assume everything I'm saying now, is just cosmetic, right?

Comment: @Murphy1976 yep, it's that easy. Only note here is I wouldn't use `$('body').on('change', 'input[type=range]', ...)` because presence of any other range input on the page will screw up the logics.

Comment: Yes, you can just output the object value to the tooltip text.  Everytime the range input is moved, have the tooltip update.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, this was just for a quick demo!  I would give the input range a name so you can be more specific!

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753946/html5-slider-with-two-inputs-possible). The solution offered is to use the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range).

To answer the part of your question specific to your case, you will probably need to build the array of possible values (like you've done above: `notesArr = ['Gb3', 'G3' ... 'Bb5', 'B5'];` and in the ui-slider code, set the `min` to 0 and the `max` to `notesArr.length - 1`. In the portion of the code that defines the label, use the integer value of the slider position to index into the array to get the string value to display.

Comment: I was HOPING that I could apply this to an already well established UI Library.... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery UI slider you can do something like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EHLQL/167/):

```
    $(function () {
    var note =  ['Gb3', 'G3', 'G#3', 'Ab3', 'A3', 'A#5', 'Bb5', 'B5'];
        $("#slider-range-min").slider({
            range: true,
            values: [0,7],
            min: 0,
            max: 7,          
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {           
                $("#amount").val(note[ui.values[0]]+ "-"+note[ui.values[1]]);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val(note[0]+ "-"+note[7]);

});
```