# Material Design Range Slider: 2 inputs/handles possible?

Tags: jquery, html, slider, material-design

Can we use 2 inputs in material design range slider ?

It seems possible to do this using Jquery as answered in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753946/html5-slider-with-two-inputs-possible). But I cannot use jquery.

I have searched the net without any results. Any help would be invaluable.

Comment: Have you tried using Jquery? If so, what problems did you run into? We can only really help you with a specific problem, and if you are having a specific problem, you will need to post your code.

Comment: I cannot use jquery in my product. I have to do this using html5 and material design.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies things. Maybe you could edit your question to include that information, just so that it's easier for folks to understand?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the second line. Let me elaborate it further.